# How can I revert syntax from Cypher 2.0.1 to Cypher 2.0.0 for my Neo4j queries?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am using a series of nested FOREACH loops in a query that functions properly on a number of installations of Neo4j with matching datasets that we've used for testing. With the recent change to Cypher 2.0.1, my query doesn't work.

My initial instinct is to replace the `/var/lib/neo4j/lib/neo4j-cypher-2.0.0.jar` files, but I don't want to screw things up. Any thoughts?

Sample graph: http://console.neo4j.org/?id=ktrcwx

Here's the Query (my emphasis "**" indicates the point where error occurs):

```
$ MATCH (total:Recipe)
>     WITH count(DISTINCT total) AS tots, timestamp() AS time
>     MATCH (ia:Ingredient)<-[:HAS_INGREDIENT]-(recab:Recipe)-[recHasB:HAS_INGREDIENT]->(ib:Ingredient)
>       WHERE id(ia)=5167
>       WITH DISTINCT ib AS idB, count(DISTINCT recab) AS recAB , count(DISTINCT recHasB) AS recB, tots, time
>     MATCH (i:Ingredient)<-[:HAS_INGREDIENT]-(r:Recipe)
>       WHERE id(i)=5167
>       WITH [i, count(DISTINCT r.id), idB, recAB, recB, tots, time] AS c
>     FOREACH (row IN c |
>       FOREACH (i1 in **c[0] |**
>         FOREACH (recA in c[1] |
>           FOREACH (i2 in c[2]|
>             FOREACH (recAB in c[3] |
>               FOREACH (recB in c[4] |
>                 FOREACH (totalRec in c[5] |
>                   CREATE (i1:Ingredient )-[pm1:PMI]->(i2: Ingredient)
>                   SET startNode(pm1).pmiTime = c[6], endNode(pm1).pmiTime = c[6], pm1.weight = log( (totalRec*recAB) /(recA*recB) ), pm1.pmiTime= c[6]
>                   CREATE (i1:Ingredient )<-[pm2:PMI]-(i2: Ingredient)
>                   SET startNode(pm2).pmiTime = c[6], endNode(pm2).pmiTime = c[6], pm2.weight = log( (totalRec*recAB) /(recA*recB) ), pm2.pmiTime= c[6]
>                 )
>               )
>             )
>           )
>         )
>       )
>     );
```

Here's the Error:

```
SyntaxException: Type mismatch: expected Collection<T> but was Any (line 10, column 25)"      FOREACH (i1 in c[0] |"
```

Here's the Functioning Classpath:

```
Neo4j Server is running at pid 4347
NEO4J_HOME:        /var/lib/neo4j
NEO4J_SERVER_PORT: 7474
NEO4J_INSTANCE:    /var/lib/neo4j
JAVA_HOME:
JAVA_OPTS:         -server -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Dorg.neo4j.server.properties=conf/neo4j-server.properties -Djava.util.logging.config.file=conf/logging.properties -Dlog4j.configuration=file:conf/log4j.properties -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
CLASSPATH:         /var/lib/neo4j/lib/concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru-1.3.1.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/lib/geronimo-jta_1.1_spec-1.1.1.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/lib/lucene-core-3.6.2.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/lib/neo4j-cypher-2.0.0.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/lib/neo4j-cypher-commons-2.0.0.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/lib/neo4j-cypher-compiler-1.9-2.0.0.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/lib/neo4j-cypher-compiler-2.0-2.0.0.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/lib/neo4j-graph-algo-2.0.0.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/lib/neo4j-graph-matching-2.0.0.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/lib/neo4j-jmx-2.0.0.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/lib/neo4j-kernel-2.0.0.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/lib/neo4j-lucene-index-2.0.0.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/lib/neo4j-shell-2.0.0.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/lib/neo4j-udc-2.0.0.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/lib/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jline-0.9.94_1.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/lib/parboiled-core-1.1.6.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/lib/parboiled-scala_2.10-1.1.6.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/lib/scala-library-2.10.3.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/lib/server-api-2.0.0.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/system/lib/asm-3.1.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/system/lib/bcprov-jdk16-140.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/system/lib/commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/system/lib/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/system/lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/system/lib/commons-compiler-2.6.1.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/system/lib/commons-configuration-1.6.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/system/lib/commons-digester-1.8.1.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/system/lib/commons-io-1.4.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/system/lib/commons-lang-2.4.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/system/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/system/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.7.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/system/lib/jackson-jaxrs-1.9.7.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/system/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.7.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/system/lib/janino-2.6.1.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/system/lib/javax.servlet-3.0.0.v201112011016.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/system/lib/jcl-over-slf4j-1.6.1.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/system/lib/jersey-core-1.9.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/system/lib/jersey-multipart-1.9.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/system/lib/jersey-server-1.9.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/system/lib/jetty-http-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/system/lib/jetty-io-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/system/lib/jetty-security-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/system/lib/jetty-server-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/system/lib/jetty-servlet-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/system/lib/jetty-util-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/system/lib/jetty-webapp-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/system/lib/jetty-xml-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/system/lib/jsr311-api-1.1.2.r612.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/system/lib/logback-access-1.0.9.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/system/lib/logback-classic-1.0.9.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/system/lib/logback-core-1.0.9.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/system/lib/mimepull-1.6.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/system/lib/neo4j-browser-2.0.0.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/system/lib/neo4j-server-2.0.0.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/system/lib/neo4j-server-2.0.0-static-web.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/system/lib/rhino-1.7R3.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/system/lib/rrd4j-2.0.7.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/system/lib/slf4j-api-1.6.2.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/conf/
```

Here's the Malfunctioning Classpath:

```
Neo4j Server is running at pid 1361
NEO4J_HOME:        /var/lib/neo4j
NEO4J_SERVER_PORT: 7474
NEO4J_INSTANCE:    /var/lib/neo4j
JAVA_HOME:
JAVA_OPTS:         -server -XX:+DisableExplicitGC - Dorg.neo4j.server.properties=conf/neo4j-server.properties -Djava.util.logging.config.file=conf/logging.properties -Dlog4j.configuration=file:conf/log4j.properties -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
CLASSPATH:         /var/lib/neo4j/lib/concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru-1.3.1.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/lib/geronimo-jta_1.1_spec-1.1.1.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/lib/lucene-core-3.6.2.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/lib/neo4j-cypher-2.0.1.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/lib/neo4j-cypher-commons-2.0.1.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/lib/neo4j-cypher-compiler-1.9-2.0.1.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/lib/neo4j-cypher-compiler-2.0-2.0.1.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/lib/neo4j-graph-algo-2.0.1.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/lib/neo4j-graph-matching-2.0.1.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/lib/neo4j-jmx-2.0.1.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/lib/neo4j-kernel-2.0.1.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/lib/neo4j-lucene-index-2.0.1.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/lib/neo4j-shell-2.0.1.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/lib/neo4j-udc-2.0.1.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/lib/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jline-0.9.94_1.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/lib/parboiled-core-1.1.6.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/lib/parboiled-scala_2.10-1.1.6.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/lib/scala-library-2.10.3.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/lib/server-api-2.0.1.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/system/lib/asm-3.1.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/system/lib/bcprov-jdk16-140.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/system/lib/commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/system/lib/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/system/lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/system/lib/commons-compiler-2.6.1.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/system/lib/commons-configuration-1.6.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/system/lib/commons-digester-1.8.1.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/system/lib/commons-io-1.4.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/system/lib/commons-lang-2.4.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/system/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/system/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.7.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/system/lib/jackson-jaxrs-1.9.7.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/system/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.7.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/system/lib/janino-2.6.1.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/system/lib/javax.servlet-3.0.0.v201112011016.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/system/lib/jcl-over-slf4j-1.6.1.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/system/lib/jersey-core-1.9.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/system/lib/jersey-multipart-1.9.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/system/lib/jersey-server-1.9.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/system/lib/jetty-http-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/system/lib/jetty-io-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/system/lib/jetty-security-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/system/lib/jetty-server-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/system/lib/jetty-servlet-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/system/lib/jetty-util-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/system/lib/jetty-webapp-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/system/lib/jetty-xml-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/system/lib/jsr311-api-1.1.2.r612.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/system/lib/logback-access-1.0.9.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/system/lib/logback-classic-1.0.9.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/system/lib/logback-core-1.0.9.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/system/lib/mimepull-1.6.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/system/lib/neo4j-browser-2.0.1.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/system/lib/neo4j-server-2.0.1.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/system/lib/neo4j-server-2.0.1-static-web.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/system/lib/rhino-1.7R3.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/system/lib/rrd4j-2.0.7.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/system/lib/slf4j-api-1.6.2.jar:/var/lib/neo4j/conf/
```

Notes on intended outcome: 
For every row in the collection, the query should create 2 relations: `(i1)-[:PMI]->(i2)` and `(i2)-[:PMI]->(i1)`. The weight of the `[:PMI]` relations is the math in the `Log()` function. The graph is `(:Ingredient)` and `(:Recipe)` nodes. This query will create a relationship between `(i1:Ingredient)` and every `(i2:Ingredient)` that occurs in the recipe containing `(i1)`. This allows me to understand probability of ingredient pairings.

Comment: It might be helpful to explain what the query is supposed to do. I think you'll find that there is much more succinct ways to express what you want, that will work fine with 2.0.1.

Comment: For every row in the collection, the query should create a relation: A->B and A<-B. The weight of these relations is the math in the Log() function.  

The graph is :Ingredient and :Recipe nodes. This query will create a relationship between A:Ingredient and every B:Ingredient that is included in every recipe that A is found in. This allows me to understand probability of ingredient pairings. 

I'm sure there are more concise ways to make this work, and I'm grateful for input in that area, however my question is why this query correctly creates the relations in 2.0.0 but not 2.0.1.

Comment: The reason this doesn't work in 2.0.1, is that it relies on a bug that was present in 2.0.0 and has since been fixed. In the example above, the `c` collection is a mixture of all different typed things, so Cypher works its overall type out as "Collection<Any>" - meaning each thing inside is only an 'Any' (the least useful type). The bug in 2.0.0 was that something having type 'Any' was actually accepted pretty much anywhere (ie. the type checking failed for Any).

Comment: That's a very helpful explanation. So, if I grouped the columns in `c` into the constituent Nodes & Integers, I should then be able to use them correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Can you wrap your non-collection items in `[ ]` and see if that solves the problem? For example: `FOREACH(i1 IN [c[0]] |`

Ok, here's an attempt at a slight rewrite that compiles--would be great if you could post some example data on console.neo4j.org if it doesn't work:

```
MATCH (total:Recipe)
WITH count(DISTINCT total) AS tots, timestamp() AS time
MATCH (ia:Ingredient)<-[:HAS_INGREDIENT]-(recab:Recipe)-[recHasB:HAS_INGREDIENT]->(ib:Ingredient)
WHERE id(ia)=5167
WITH DISTINCT ib AS idB, count(DISTINCT recab) AS recAB , count(DISTINCT recHasB) AS recB, tots, time
MATCH (i:Ingredient)<-[:HAS_INGREDIENT]-(r:Recipe)
WHERE id(i)=5167
WITH i, count(DISTINCT r.id) as recA, idB as i2, recAB, recB, tots, time  
CREATE (i)-[pm1:PMI {pmiTime:time, weight:log( (tots*recAB) /(recA*recB) )}]->(i2)
CREATE (i)<-[pm2:PMI {pmiTime:time, weight:log( (tots*recAB) /(recA*recB) )}]-(i2)
SET i.pmiTime = time, pm1.pmiTime = time, i2.pmiTime = time, pm2.pmiTime = time
```

Comment: Also, why are you iterating over row IN c, and then using c[0] and the like? Feels wrong.

Comment: Totally agree, this is a hacky query. Happy to have some input about ways to improve the way it works. It took me several days to get it working in the first case. How to make this work in 2.0.1? It still works on my deployed and testing servers which are on 2.0.0, however it won't work on the new server I'm trying to build with 2.0.1.

Comment: Also, yes... I've wrapped all my queries according to your suggestion. I get a different error now (with pointer on 'totalRec'): 

    SyntaxException: Type mismatch: expected Double or Integer but was Any (line 17, column 102)
"                  SET startNode(pm1).pmiTime = c[6], endNode(pm1).pmiTime = c[6], pm1.weight = log( (totalRec*recAB) /(recA*recB) ), pm1.pmiTime= c[6]"

I get a diff error when I replace totalRec with [c[5]]:  Type mismatch: expected Double or Integer but was Any (line 17, column 105)

Comment: Thanks very much for your help @Wes. It doesn't quite work, though. That query makes many relationships, but gives all of them the same weight. I'll work on getting some sample data to the link you provided.

Comment: Can you explain your expected results?

Comment: What I really want is to be able to use Cypher 2.0.0 instead of Cypher 2.0.1. In lieu of that, I want to create the [:PMI] relationship between all all ingredients in the DB

Comment: AFAIK, you can't use Cypher 2.0.0 in Neo4j 2.0.1 and expect things to line up properly.

Comment: I'll investigate two things: Learning about how to correctly use Collections, and installing Neo4j 2.0.0 . Thanks for all the help :)

Comment: @lazaruslarue Best to figure out the way to write the query with 2.0.1 - otherwise you'll be stuck on 2.0.0 forever. Wes is pretty good at figuring this stuff out, if you can explain what the query is trying to do and should be returning.